Access Denied While Creating AWS Glue Crawler Despite Granting Necessary Permissions
I'm encountering an "Access Denied" error when trying to create an AWS Glue crawler. I have already provided all the necessary permissions to the IAM user and role, but I still can't create the crawler. Could someone provide clear steps and list all the required permissions for the IAM user and role to successfully create a crawler in AWS Glue?
Here's what I've done so far Polices attaced to the IAM role created
Verified the IAM role trust relationship:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}

Checked the S3 bucket policy (if applicable):
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::834715106494:role/YourGlueServiceRole"
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketName",
        "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketName/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Despite these configurations, I'm still facing access issues. Can someone provide a detailed guide on setting up the correct permissions for creating a Glue crawler?
Thank you!

With this bucket policy, if you are not allowing public access to the bucket, I would say you couldn't access the bucket even from the UI with admin permissions. Is that the case?

I have allowed the public acess to the bucket but even though I am getting the same eroor.Could you please help me with that?

@AnuAnusha You need to add glue actions for your glue job first in your permissions. Crawler uses glue jobs to begin with. Have you added them?
